# Using jQuery Confirmation box to update ColdFusion Function

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have a confirmation box that pops up when click on a link. I need it to fire off a function when you click OK

Currently this is my code:

JQUERY

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        // confirm box
        if(jQuery('.confirmbutton').length > 0) {
        jQuery('.confirmbutton').click(function(){
        jConfirm('You are about to delete your Profile Photo.'
                        , 'Delete Profile Photo', function(r) {
        if (r == true) {
    $.get('core/functions/queryUpdates.cfc?method=delProfilePhoto&userID=#SESSION.User.ID#'),
    jAlert('Your Profile Photo is now deleted.', 'Thank You');
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).dialog("close");    
                    }
                });
            });
        }

    });
```

COLDFUSION

```
<cffunction name="delProfilePhoto" access="remote" returntype="string">
    <cfargument name="userID" type="string" required="yes">
    <cfmail to="email" from="email" subject="foo">
        bar
    </cfmail>
</cffunction>
```

With my current code the function does not fire off nor do I receive the jAlert. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What is function(r) supposed to accomplish?

Comment: its a confirmation message response action

Comment: have you tried console.log(r) and confirming that the response from your confirmation box is in fact == true?

Comment: Standard if/else troubleshooting.  If you have expected value, output "expected value" else output "expected this got that".